# How to create front-end custom form with one textbox and submit button in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders, forms

I am interested in creating a **submission form** that allows users to **submit order decline remarks**.

I just need it to be a simple form with input box and submit button when do I submit form, form data should be store in table.

I have come across several tutorials that allow you to extend a basic contact form but that will not work in this instance.

Any general guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: explain what you have exactly try?

Comment: i have created a form with text box and create controller for it  .. <form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline'); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" id="decline" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" onclick="namet()" />
  </form>

Comment: Where you need to show this form and where you need to save this value?

Comment: i am using order approval extension i want to add text field for approval and cancel remarks. as admin cancel order than remarks for cancel should be send on customer shopping cart page

Comment: You need to used refrenceblock to add your form to that page or customized that extension.

Comment: i did not get you can you explain step by step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50381/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-dhiren-vasoya).